# how to call object method from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

```
var ssOffCanvas = function() {
           var menuTrigger = $('#header-menu-trigger'),
           nav             = $('#menu-nav-wrap'),
           closeButton     = nav.find('.close-button'),
           siteBody        = $('body'),
           mainContents    = $('section, footer');

        // open-close menu by clicking on the menu icon
        menuTrigger.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            menuTrigger.toggleClass('is-clicked');
            siteBody.toggleClass('menu-is-open');
        });
   };

proj_request_menu.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
};
```

What it the most suitable way to call `ssOffCanvas` object `menuTrigger` in proj_request_menu function. I know to handle this within the object.
    Ex: `menuTrigger.trigger('click');`
    Need your help ...

Comment: You need to return `menuTrigger` from `ssOffCanvas` in order to access it outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Fist you have to modify your object definition so your variable is accessible from the outside. Right now, when you create a variable inside the object with the `var` keyword (or `const` or `let`) its considered a private property that can only be used inside that object. So you have to make it a privileged one with the keyword `this` (privileged properties of the object can be accessed from the outside) like this:

```
var ssOffCanvas = function(){
    this.menuTrigger = $('#header-menu-trigger');
    ...
};
```

Note the `this` keyword in `this.menuTrigger`.

To get the property of the object first you have to instantiate it:

```
let myCanvas = new ssOffCanvas();
```

And then you will be able to get the property:

```
myCanvas.menuTrigger; // returns $('#header-menu-trigger') value
```

Do the same with the other properties. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: If you want your object property to be accessible from the outside what you have to do is to remove the `var` or `let` and use `this.yourProperty`. `let` does the same as the `var` keyword but the `let` variable is not accessible before declared and is not accessible from outside the block it is declared. Ideal for keeping your code error free because `var` does some weird stuff like hoisting that you want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

As menuMenuTrigger is not accessible from outside ssOffCanvas function the fastest way (least code to change) would be to pull it out of the current function like so:

```
// now menu Trigger is available on the global scope
// and could be called from everywhere
var menuTrigger = $('#header-menu-trigger');

var ssOffCanvas = function() {
   var nav             = $('#menu-nav-wrap'),
       closeButton     = nav.find('.close-button'),
       siteBody        = $('body'),
       mainContents    = $('section, footer');

    // open-close menu by clicking on the menu icon
    menuTrigger.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        menuTrigger.toggleClass('is-clicked');
        siteBody.toggleClass('menu-is-open');
    });
};

proj_request_menu.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";

    // now it is available here, too.
    menuTrigger.trigger('click')
};
```

I am not quite sure if that is what you intended...

Comment: getting error "ReferenceError: menuTrigger is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

since nothing workout added code into the object.

```
$('#proj_request_menu').on('click',function(){
            menuTrigger.trigger('click');
            });
```

Final Code As Follows:

```
var ssOffCanvas = function() {

           var menuTrigger = $('#header-menu-trigger'),
           nav             = $('#menu-nav-wrap'),
           closeButton     = nav.find('.close-button'),
           siteBody        = $('body'),
           mainContents    = $('section, footer');


        // open-close menu by clicking on the menu icon
        menuTrigger.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            menuTrigger.toggleClass('is-clicked');
            siteBody.toggleClass('menu-is-open');
        });

        // close menu by clicking the close button
        closeButton.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            menuTrigger.trigger('click');   
        });

        // close menu clicking outside the menu itself
        siteBody.on('click', function(e){       
            if( !$(e.target).is('#menu-nav-wrap, #header-menu-trigger, #header-menu-trigger span') ) {
                menuTrigger.removeClass('is-clicked');
                siteBody.removeClass('menu-is-open');
            }
        });
        $('#proj_request_menu').on('click',function(){
            menuTrigger.trigger('click');
            });

   };
var proj_request_menu= document.getElementById("proj_request_menu");
proj_request_menu.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "block";
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Make menuTrigger global?

```
var menuTrigger=null;
var ssOffCanvas = function() {
       menuTrigger = $('#header-menu-trigger'),
       nav             = $('#menu-nav-wrap'),
       closeButton     = nav.find('.close-button'),
       siteBody        = $('body'),
       mainContents    = $('section, footer');

    // open-close menu by clicking on the menu icon
    menuTrigger.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        menuTrigger.toggleClass('is-clicked');
        siteBody.toggleClass('menu-is-open');
    });
};

proj_reququest_menu.onclick = function() {
if(menuTrigger) menuTrigger.trigger("click");
};
```

Comment: my requirement is to trigger code which uses to do open-close menu.